# Data structure for storing recurring events?

Tags: language-agnostic, design-patterns, data-structures

I'm looking for a data structure pattern for storing recurring events, but everything I came up with would result in a high number of special case handling or user input and data retrieval are overly complex. (I get the distinct feeling, that I haven't understand the problem domain well enough to do this.)

How can I store Outlook-style recurring events?

- Every day at 8am
- Every first tuesday in a month
- Every December 1st for three years
- Every two hours for a week
- ...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are various papers describing data structures and algorithms for this use case. In addition you can see the code or descriptions of open source implementation of [crontab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) and of [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) (Java) or [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) (.NET).

This is one such paper

http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=359763.359801&coll=ACM&dl=ACM&CFID=63647367&CFTOKEN=55814330

For example, cron stores the information like this (`*` means every, so a `*` under month means every month)

```
.---------------- minute (0 - 59) 
|  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
|  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
|  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ... 
|  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)  OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat 
|  |  |  |  |
*  *  *  *  * 

There are several special entries, most of which are just shortcuts, 
that can be used instead of specifying the full cron entry:

Entry      Description                 Equivalent To
@reboot    Run once, at startup.       None
@yearly    Run once a year             0 0 1 1 *
@annually  (same as @yearly)           0 0 1 1 *
@monthly   Run once a month            0 0 1 * *
@weekly    Run once a week             0 0 * * 0
@daily     Run once a day              0 0 * * *
@midnight  (same as @daily)            0 0 * * *
@hourly    Run once an hour            0 * * * *
```

Answer (score 18):

**Support the standard *iCalendar* Event types**

The IETF put some thought into this when they created the *Internet Calendaring and Scheduling Core Object Specification*, better known as ***iCalendar***.

The specification includes event recurrence.

As an added bonus, your database will be amenable to sharing data with other iCalendar compatible data sources such as Google and Apple calendars.

> https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545

Answer (score 6):

```
Event:

StartDate
EndDate (calculated on change of NumberOfOccurances)
NumberOfOccurances (calculated on change of EndDate )
Frequency e.g. 1/2hrs, 1/month, 1/day, ....
CorrectionFunction e.g. first Tuesday, last Sunday, ...

bool OccuresOn(day)
Date NextOccurance(date)
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is my take -- please let me know if I am missing anything:

Based on the Outlook Recurrence options, you have a table with the regular necessary fields:

```
FieldName       DataType      Sample Data
ID              int           primary key
EventID         int           foreign key (to EventID from Event Table)
StartTime       DateTime      8:00 AM
EndTime         DateTime      8:30 AM
Duration        int           30 (minutes)
StartDate       DateTime      01/25/2014
EndBy           DateTime      01/25/2024
NoEndDate       bit           False
NumOccurrences  int           10
RecurrenceType  int           ****See below for instructions on how to use these last 6 fields  
Int1            int           
Int2            int
Int3            int
String1         nvarchar(50)
IntYears        int
```

Here is where the magic happens. this logic only requires 4 integers and one string.

```
The month of year (1 = Jan, 12 = Dec), 
The day of the month (1 = the 1st, 31 = 31st), 
Day of the week (0 = Sunday, 1=Monday, 6= Saturday), 
Week of the month (1 = first, 4 = forth, 5 = last),
Yearly reocurrence ( 1=1,2=2)   
When multiple days can be selected I use a comma delimited string (1,3,5 = Monday, Wed, Friday)
```

I enter the 3 integers in the order they appear in the outlook Appointment Recurrence scheduler, this saves extra feilds, logic, annoyance.
****If you open to the outlook appt scheduler, this will be slightly easier to follow:***

```
The RecurrenceType field can be any of the 7 following choices
```

(There are 2 options for daily, Monthly and Yearly, and one option for weekly):

```
10 = Daily (Every `Int1` day(s) )    
            Every     4  day(s)
11 = Daily (Every Weekday)  -- no variables needed 
            Every Weekday (MTWTF)
20 = Weekly (Recur every `Int1` week(s) on: `String1`
             Recur every     3  week(s) on  Monday, Wednesday, Friday   
(`String1` will be a list of days selected (0=Sunday, 1=Monday, 2=Tuesday... 7=Saturday) so for (Mon, Wed, Fri) String1 would hold "1,3,5". You would parse this on the code side to pull the actual days.)
30 = Monthly (Day `Int1` of every `int2' month(s) 
              Day    28  of every     2  month(s)
31 = Monthly (The `Int1`  `Int2` of every `Int3` month(s) 
              The forth Tuesday  of every     1  month(s)
40 = Yearly (Recur every `intYears` year(s) On `Int1` `Int2`) -- 
             Recur every         1  year(s) on   Jan   28th
41 = Yearly (Recur every `intYears` year(s) on the `Int1` `Int2` of `Int3`) -- 
             Recur every         1  year(s) on the forth Tuesday of January
```

The code to pull or save the reocurrence becomes fairly simple

```
if (RecurrenceType = 10 )
    Every `int1` days
if (RecurrenceType = 11)
    Every Weekday
if (RecurrenceType = 20)
    Every `int1 weeks on 
    parse `string1` and populate checkboxes for Mon, Tues, ...
if (RecurrenceType = 30)
    `int1 day of every `int2` month

etc...
```

I hope I am explaining this thoroughly enough. Let me know if anything is unclear or if it will not work. I am building this for a current app. Thanks to all.

Comment: Hey! Great answer! It leaves me with one open question: Is there a fast way of calculating all the dates between the start date and the end by date, without iterating each date?